# How to achieve MVCC in actor model

Tags: concurrency, actor

Let's say I have represented my Employee entity as an actor. I have 2 services also modeled as actors. Both of them manipulate the state of an Employee actor it has received by sending it messages. Now let's say both the services are processing the same actor. Now it is perfectly possible that an employee actor receive state changing messages in the following order from the two services A and B

`Employee <- |a1|a2|a3|b1|b2|b3|`

This is fine. But sometimes its not

`Employee <- |a1|b1|a2|b2|a3|b3|`

Maybe `a2` was dependent on state changed by `a1`, but `b1` changed it

In analogy to databases, we have transactions so that we can work with a single snapshot/version of the data throughout the transactions lifetime.

In imperative model, we would lock the whole employee object and update its state similar to how database would do it.

So is it possible that an actor can receive bulked messages that will be processed as one atomic series of messages? Or is my modeling of my data itself flawed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I don't know what a1-a3 and b1-b3 actually represent, I can only assume to answer the question correctly. To me it appears that your messages are too fine grained. For example, perhaps a1-a3 are trying to set just one attribute of data in each message. The same probably goes for b1-b3.

However, what your messages should be focused on is causing behaviors on the Employee, not in setting individual attributes. Thus, as you yourself suggest, design your messages as behaviors, where a1-a3 would collapse into a single operation request. This is often called the Command pattern, where you command/tell an object/actor to do something. Doing so will result in correct transactional boundaries per message.

Note that above I said "object/actor." You can/should use the same approach in your object designs, not just for actors. Think in terms of intention-revealing interfaces and telling your domain model what you want it to do for you, rather than treating domain objects/actors as dumb data holders.

That's my take on your question. HTH.

Vaughn

Comment: That's what I ended up with. Whatever changes that I would've written inside a transaction block, I made a message that completely performs that transaction using a single message! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Both of them manipulate the state of an Employee actor it has received
>   by sending it messages.

Well. An Actor by definition does not share its state or its manipulation with any other Actor. Any state manipulation is transactional within the boundaries of *one* message handling. An Actor represents an aggregate in that sense. Messages usually are *Domain* events/commands and have scope and part of the Ubiquitous language. 
DDD reasoning helps a lot when thinking about Actors.

My two cents

Sergiy
<><

Comment: "mutation/transactional behaviour must be bounded within a single message". Glad that this is the kind of pattern we actually need to apply in actor model

Comment: Hence, I really like how DDD and ActorModel paradigms converge, making EventSourcing and CQRS the natural choices, giving Eventual Consistency its proper place.

Comment: @SergiyChernets I recall your talk in Microsoft Channel9 show - DDD and CQRS on Service Fabric . The talk on theory part and diagrams were great, but (demo) implementation was a bit under my expectations. Too clunky and lot of supporting code, which distracts the focus from actual domain. I think, the problem is the C# syntax itself. I implemented similar concepts with Erlang and that was much elegant. Have you maybe tried F# instead?

Comment: @ajukraine Three things I should point out. First, the code we demoed is not the real one. Obviously. :) That code was created within 1 hour span. To show the approach and conceptual connection between DDD and Actor Model. Second, It is an abstraction on top of the Virtual Actors of Service Fabric. Third, we work on Azure platform with tech stack that is available. 
Elegance of a specific implementation language always helps, I agree.